# É possível criptografar a senha de conexão com o banco de dados que fica dentro de uma aplicação Java?

Tags: java, postgresql, md5

Estou com uma aplicação em Java e usando o banco PostgreSQL. Pra fazer a conexão junto ao banco utilizo esse método:

```
    public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(Constantes.URL_BD, Constantes.USUARIO_BD, Constantes.SENHA_BD);

            return connection;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Gostaria de saber se ao passar a senha para o método getConnection () de DriverManager ela pode estar encriptada de alguma maneira... seja usando md5 ou outro tipo de hash.

Comment: Qual o motivo pelo qual quer este resultado? Vamos tentar tratar o motivo.

Comment: Eu quero fazer isso para o caso de alguém conseguir acesso a minha aplicação, seja por código de fonte ou engenharia reversa não conseguir ler a senha

Comment: Sua aplicação é Desktop se comunicando com um banco remoto?

Comment: Isso rodo por linha de comando .jar

Comment: Como você usa o banco? É viável separar nesse front-end CLI e um serviço que se comunica com o banco? (Serviço esse que se situa em um ambiente controlado)